# SSH not working on windows bash?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows 10 Pro. Using bash shell there. When I type SSH command it says

```
MINGW64 ~
$ ssh
bash: ssh: command not found
```

My understanding bash will be able to execute all linux commands. Isn't it ? Command `lS` works. Do I need to do anything else here ?

Comment: "My understanding bash will be able to execute all linux commands` -- `ssh` is a standalone executable, not a shell builtin. Bash can run executables that are available. Either there is no `ssh` at all, or `ssh` is somewhere but not reachable via `$PATH`. This is not an answer because I don't know WSL and I cannot help you with installing `ssh`. I'm only pointing out the existence of `bash` does not mean you can run `ssh` or any other external command. `ls` is also a standalone executable, but it's apparently where it should be, therefore it works.

Comment: Instead of using the WSL for ssh, I would recommend using either Putty or Git Bash for Windows. Then you don't need to mess with the WSL, which is very nice, but does not work for everything that well

Comment: MINGW is not WSL and never was "windows bash". Why use it when WSL exists and is the real Linux?

Comment: @harrymc I am using windows10 pro ? Do I have to separately install WSL as when I try wsl in window search bar/command prompt nothing comes up ?

Comment: @harrymc second question is on  `MINGW is not WSL and never was windows bash` When I type bash shell , MINGW  prompt opens up , so its not wsl ? When i google search `What is Bash on Windows?` it says `Bash on Windows provides a Windows subsystem and Ubuntu Linux runs atop it. Basically, it allows you to run the same Bash shell that you find on Linux` Not sure What I am missing here ?

Comment: [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) is an optional Windows feature. I suggest to uninstall MINGW and then enable this feature and install your favorite Linux distribution from the Windows Store.

Comment: Can you please answer second part of query too ?

Comment: I don't know MINGW, but WSL (the real one) is a full Linux system that includes access to the repository of the chosen Linux distribution for adding packages. It has almost everything except graphical support (but even this is forthcoming).

Comment: Is the above good enough for my posting an answer?

Comment: I agree with @harrymc that you are *not* running WSL.  There are multiple ways to get Bash on Windows, not just WSL.  Given the `MING64`, I would think Git Bash (from Git for Windows) would be the most likely candidate, but Git Bash *does* include `ssh`.  Can you find the file path for the Bash that you are running and add it to your question?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Interesting I am able to do `ssh` from Gitbash. I am bit confused when I type bash in windows search bar I see two options `Bash Shell` (location is `~`) and `GitBash` (Location is `MING64:user/users/username`). Once they open i see `MING64` written on both prompt so what the diff  b/w bashshell and git bash ?

Comment: Not sure what the second one is.  Really need to know the *Windows* path to that "Bash Shell".  That might give you some indication.  Good to know that you can `ssh` from GitBash, though.  That's as I would expect.  You can also, as harrymc pointed out, still install WSL.  That can be done by following the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).  Note that the "Simplified install" *only* works if you have Insider/Preview version of Windows.  Recommend that you start WSL using the `wsl` command, though, not the `Ubuntu` or `bash` legacy commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ssh client or to make sure the folder where the binaries are installed to is in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using debian in wsl2 and I was facing the same issue.
In my case I fixed the issue by installing the openssh-client. For debian/ubuntu the command is apt install openssh-client.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the Terminal app from the windows store. When a distro is installed you can change your shell (by clicking the down arrow next to the tab).

https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701

If you are in your distro (probably Ubuntu) and ssh still won't work, you may need to install ssh (to check if it is installed type 'whereis ssh' in your distros shell).

Comment: It is clear that the OP is *not* using WSL, so this isn't going to help.